# Decoding JSON array using Codable in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I've spent considerable time looking this and looking at examples on SO / web but I cannot see what I've done wrong.

I have the following JSON being returned by a REST server:

```
{
        "data":{
            "customers":
            [
              {
                    "customerId":27,
                    "customerName":"Dispatch Tool Customer 1"
              }
            ]
        },
        "error":"<null>",
        "ok":1
    }
```

And the following classes representing this data:

```
public class ResponseBase : Codable
{
    public var ok : Int?
    public var error : String?
}

public class CustomersResponse : ResponseBase
{
    public class Customer : Codable
    {
        public var customerName : String?
        public var customerId : Int?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case customerId = "customerId"
            case customerName = "customerName"
        }

        required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            customerId = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .customerId)
            customerName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .customerName)
        }
    }

    public class Data : Codable
    {
        public var customers : [Customer]?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case customers = "customers"
        }

        required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            customers = try values.decodeIfPresent([Customer].self, forKey: .customers)
        }
    }

    public var data : Data?


    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case error = "error"
        case ok = "ok"
    }

    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        super.init()
        data = try Data(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

And the following code uses Alamofire 4.0 to call the server and then processes the response using the JSON decoding capabilities in Swift:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON
            {
                response in
                print(response)
                print("=============================================================")

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                    let model = try decoder.decode(CustomersResponse.self, from: response.data!)
                    print("done model")
                } catch let error {
                    print("ERROR")
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

"ok" and "error" are being decoded correctly. "data" is being decoded too, but "customers" is always nil. Originally I had the classes without the initialisers and CodingKeys but, of course, I get the same result.

I am printing out the response and I can see that the JSON is correctly coming down (although why it's not printed out in standard JSON format is something I don't understand - why does Alamofire replace the [ with ( and the : with = ?  The JSON from the server is correctly formatted JSON).

I'm not sure what else I can try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you are using Alamofire's json response, which mean, the result is already been transformed into a json object, or a dictionary in cocoa convention.
By using codable to decode/encode, the in/out value should be Data type. That's why you see the value with something looked like already decoded.

Second, I am not sure what you want to achieve, so I will put down the simplest format.

```
struct Customer: Decodable{
    let customerId: Int
    let customerName: String
}

struct ServerResponse: Decodable {
    let ok: Int
    let error: String?
    let data: [Customer]
}
```

This is the simplest way to decode the response. For ServerResponse, instead of subclassing it, I would also recommend using Generic type, so that you can

```
struct ServerResponse<T>: Decodable {
    let ok: Int
    let error: String?
    let data: T
}
typealias CustomerResponse = ServerResponse<[Customer]>
```

to decode any server response (of coz only apply if all your server response are well formatter)

Comment: @MathewLuiHK Thanks. I will experiment with this. I was using responseData but this was still giving me nil. Thanks for elucidating what responseJSON is returning.

Comment: Not remember so clear, please try to find Alamofire doc for json response, maybe it is storing the json value in other key. @cbn

Comment: `data` isn't an array

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that works for me. Thanks to those who answered and pointed me in the right direction:

```
struct Customer: Decodable
{
    let customerId: Int?
    let customerName: String?
}


struct CustomerData : Decodable
{
    let customers : Array<Customer>?
}


struct ServerResponse<T:Decodable> : Decodable
{
    let data : T?
    let error : String?
    let ok : Bool?
}

typealias CustomersResponse = ServerResponse<CustomerData>
```

(Note: I had an Int in the original question, but it's actually a Bool)